# How to bypass SensorManager Data with Dummy Data on Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sensormanager, sensor-fusion

I have to figure out a way to bypass sensormanager data on Android (particularly the accelerometer data). I have no clue how to proceed, as I am relatively new to Android. I have to feed dummy sensor data (preferably from a text file on the SD-Card) to replace the actual sensormanager data.

My end goal is to use this for testing an app, which uses accelerometer data to make decisions.

I should be able to feed the dummy data to all the Apps requesting the sensor data. Anyhelp or guidance will be appreciated.

PS: I would want to acheive this on Nexus-5 Android Phone.

Answer (score 1):

`SensorManager` provides the data from sensor via `SensorEventListener`.
The sensor record contains among other an array of floats. In case of `Accelerometer` there are 3 float numbers indicating the acceleration values toward X, Y, and Z axes. So within the implementation of `SensorEventListener` you can overwrite these values with the dummy ones that you need for testing.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        int type      = event.sensor.getType();
        if(type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
           float result[] = event.values;   
           // modify the values here  
        }

}
```

EDIT: For providing record generation rate you may indicate it on the `SensorManager`'s method:

```
registerListener(this, sensor, rate_in_microseconds);
```

however as the documentation indicates [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29) that the provided rate is just a hint and does not guarantee event rate.

*The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or, the desired delay between events in microseconds. Specifying the delay in microseconds only works from Android 2.3 (API level 9) onwards. For earlier releases, you must use one of the SENSOR_DELAY_* constants.*

Comment: If I want to edit this with dummy data - how can I do it? And how can I make this available to all the apps requesting this at the application layer on Android? I want to know if I should change something on the Android code itself, if yes - how do I do this?

Comment: as far as i know you cannot provide all apps with dummy sensor data. you can do that for your app

Comment: How can I handle different request rates? For ex: my app may request accel data at 20Hz or 50Hz, how can I pass the data smartly? I am trying what you have suggested..

Comment: Your approach works partially, thanks for this ! But I still have my bigger problem, bypassing with dummy data for all apps.

Comment: i dont believe android allows fake sensor data (except gps where you can use mock location), i would be surprised if you could do that